# Does Embedded Cassandra supports jdk10?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, embedded-database, embedded-cassandra

Could anyone please confirm whether Embedded cassandra supports jdk10 ? My spring boot application test cases were working fine in jdk8, but now it is not working. If anyone using Embedded Cassandra using jdk10, could you please share a sample code.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: ...and it won't ever support Java 10. It will however support Java 11 with Cassandra 4. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608 for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Embedded Cassandra won't support jdk10.